# Why is System.Windows.Forms.Timer stopping automatically when window is fulscreen or is large?

Tags: c#, zxing, aforge

Following online samples, I have written qrcode web cam reader in c# uzing zXing and aForge libraries.
I have encountered very weird behavior of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`in C#: I have dropped it on widows form, enabled it, set interval 1 second and attached tick eventhandler.

Everything seems to work normally, but when i resize(enlarge) the window to particular size, or if i make window fullscreen, the times tick event stops firing. When i bring window from fullscreen to normal size, or when i reduce window size, the timer starts again by itself automatically.

I am using following version of visual studio:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

using ZXing;

namespace QrCodeWebCamReader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         
        FilterInfoCollection filterInfoColletion;
        VideoCaptureDevice captureDevice;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            filterInfoColletion = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach(FilterInfo filterInfo in filterInfoColletion)
            {
                cboDevice.Items.Add(filterInfo.Name);
            }
            cboDevice.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            captureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterInfoColletion[cboDevice.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            captureDevice.NewFrame += CaptureDevice_NewFrame;
            captureDevice.Start();
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void CaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

            // pictureBox.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

            Bitmap img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); 

            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(img))
            {
                gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                Rectangle cropArea = new Rectangle(img.Width / 2 - 150, img.Height / 2 - 150, 300, 300);

                gr.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red,5), cropArea); 
            }


            pictureBox.Image = (Bitmap)img.Clone();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            if (captureDevice.IsRunning)
            {
                captureDevice.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("fungus");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pictureBox.Image);

            if(pictureBox.Image != null)
            {
                Rectangle cropArea = new Rectangle(pictureBox.Image.Width / 2 - 150, pictureBox.Image.Height / 2 - 150, 300, 300);
                BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
                Result result = barcodeReader.Decode((Bitmap)((Bitmap)pictureBox.Image).Clone(cropArea, pictureBox.Image.PixelFormat));
                picCropped.Image = (Bitmap)((Bitmap)pictureBox.Image).Clone(cropArea, pictureBox.Image.PixelFormat);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    txtQRCode.Text += result.ToString();
                    Console.Beep();
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

My project is configured to work with net framework 2.0

What could be the cause of this behavior and how can i prevent it from happening?

Thank you

EDIT: The only logic I can think of regarding this behavior is that maybe compiler is doing some sort of optimization / obfuscation / minimization of the generated executable code? How is it possible to turn of optimization /obfuscation / minimization in visual studio community version for c# windows forms application?

UPDATE: This behavior happens only if video is being captured. If video is not being captured, timer is not stopping.

Comment: If you comment out all the code in `Timer1_Tick()` other than the debug writelines, does it still stop working? (I assume you have a debugger attached to see the debug writeline output.)

Comment: Visual studio doesn't actually run your code (you could even write everything with Notepad and compile it through the command line without Visual Studio being installed if you wanted to). It would be better for you to tell us the version of the framework you're using, since that's what contains the WinForms libraries.

Comment: @MatthewWatson i have oommented all lines except: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("fungunsi"); but behaviour is same

Comment: @John i am using framework 2.0

Comment: _"maybe compiler is doing some sort of..."_ -- you are barking up the wrong tree. There is a bug in your code, somewhere. Or possibly in a library you're using (the thing that does the "frame capture"). Unfortunately, you failed to provide a [mcve] so it's not practical for anyone to bother to try to reproduce your problem to help you solve it. Please improve the question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I do not understand, the code i provided is minimal code that exhibits the behaviour i have encountered. DId someone try it? Shoul i provide Minimal project itself?

Comment: The timer is not at all linked to the form and has no knowledge of the form or window. As such, when you maximize the form, it is much more likely that the timer is still ticking away, but the way you observe it ticking away is flawed. Can you tell us a bit about how you observe that the timer is running or has stopped? What are you looking at/for? Do you, say, have Visual Studio on a second screen, and the debug messages stop occurring, or does the timer update the form somehow (it doesn't seem like it does).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen 
1. i have added timer to windows form by drag and drop it on windows form design from Toolbox->Components. Are there additional steps necessary?
2. On timer tick (Timer1_Tick) i have following code: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("fungus"); and when i run project, i see  output  in visual studio Output window (Debug). When enlarge or maximize window, the messages "fungus" stops appearing in Output window. When i minimize the window, the messages starts appearing again. I  do not change ui. i have removed all code from Timer1_Tick and i am only left with Debug.WriteLine.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After Extensive research, i Have replaced `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` with `System.Timers.Timer` And everything started to worked normally and errors went away.

My setup for `System.Timers.Timer` looks Like This:

```
        System.Timers.Timer timer1;
  
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(600);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.SynchronizingObject = this;
            timer1.Elapsed += Timer1_Elapsed;
            timer1.Start();
 
        }
```

But, i still have no answer what was the reason of the original error. Any info regarding this issue would be great.

Comment: That was not a good idea, you now have a potential much bigger problem.  The real issue is that the UI thread is burning 100% core, trying to keep up with the flood of paint requests for the bitmap.  The difference is that the underlying Control.BeginInvoke() call gets handled with a much higher priority, the consequence is that it can now also prevent user input from being handled.  Maybe that didn't happen yet, but might well happen on a slower machine or a larger monitor.

Comment: Proper workaround is to use what you already know, use a winforms Timer to update the PictureBox.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for information, i will keep that in mind. But until i have solution to to winforms timer issue, i am forced to stick with System.Timers.Timer

Comment: @HansPassant I have been using System.Timers.Timer since posting this answer and i have not encountered single issue from it since then. Maybe because i do not have user input on my form, except dropdown list, from which user select desired video input device?